# Handling overlap of divs

Tags: css, overlap

I want the inner part of the red circle to be white while overlapping with the blue circle and transparent for the rest so that you can see the green color.

I would be happy if someone knows how to handle this.

```css
#bigCircle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(11, 122, 30, 0.8);
}

#middleCircle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,250,0.5);
}

.smallCircle {
    margin-top: -244px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border: solid rgb(226, 85, 20);
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  }
```

```html
        <div id="bigCircle">
                <div id="middleCircle">
                    <div class="smallCircle" />
                </div>
        </div >
```

Comment: What is **conditional** here?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as `<div />`

Comment: @Paulie_D: Yes, you are right. This is not necessary. Had something else in mind regarding how to solve it when I was writing the question and did not adapt the title. Thanks for your comment. It should just show the overlap of the red with the green circle but not the overlap of the red with the blue circle. In the last case the red circle should be filled with white color.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#bigCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(11, 122, 30, 0.8);
}

#middleCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5);
}

.smallCircle {
  margin-top: -242px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  border: solid rgb(226, 85, 20) 3px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.smallCircle:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border: solid rgb(226, 85, 20) 3px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: circle(120px at 50% 130px);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigCircle">
  <div id="middleCircle">
    <div class="smallCircle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `radial-gradient` as background coloration that you make fixed and having the same position as the blue circle:

```css
#bigCircle,
#middleCircle{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(11, 122, 30, 0.8);
}

#middleCircle {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5);
}

.smallCircle {
  margin-top: -244px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  border: solid rgb(226, 85, 20);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition:1s all;
  background:radial-gradient(circle 120px at 190px 190px,#fff 99%,transparent 100%) fixed;
}
#middleCircle:hover .smallCircle {
  margin-top: -100px;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigCircle">
  <div id="middleCircle">
    <div class="smallCircle" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understood your question then might be it'll help.

**css**

```
#bigCircle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(11, 122, 30, 0.8);
}

#middleCircle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,250,0.5);
}

.smallCircle {
    margin-top: -244px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    border: solid rgb(226, 85, 20);
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  }
```